# Create an Animation with CoreAnimation similar to the Safari download animation

Tags: core-animation

Anyone know how to create an animation similar to the Safari download animation? Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? If you're referring to the animation where the item jumps from the page down into the dock, you can take a look at Apple's documentation on keyframe animation that shows how to animate along a path here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/PropertyAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006672-SW11

Comment: Yes I talk about the animation that you described. I had already read that document and I need to understand how to draw an animation across all my application window and not in a specific view? anyone know some tutorial or documentation to do that? thanks